# Universal hypersurface is a quasi-projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

I wanted to show the following proposition:

> Let $n,d \in \mathbb{N}^{\ast}$ and let us denote $V= \mathbb{K}[x_0, \dots , x_n]_d$ the vector space of homogeneous polymials. Let us consider the Universal Hypersurface
>   $$H:= \{ ([x],F) \in \mathbb{P}^n \times V \, | \, F(x) = 0 \}$$
>   Then H is a quasi-projective variety.

Actually I got stuck since I know very few things about projective varieties (only basics). I would really appreciate any hint to figure out how to prove the quasi-projectivity.

Thanks you in advance.

K. Y.

Comment: A closed subset of a quasiprojective variety is quasiprojective.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was so obvious that I feel stupid when I asked. Could you please in addition help me to show that it is a vector bundle? I actually don't have any idea of its rank.

Comment: This vector bundle is the kernel of the natural evaluation map $V \otimes \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}(d)$. The map is surjective, hence the kerbel is a vector bundle, and its rank is the difference of ranks of the other two.